# Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I need to overload the * operator in c++. So I have made a class called Element which must overload this opperator to work on a double value stored within it. This is what I have done in the implementation file:

```
#include "Element.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Other code that is not relevant

Element Element::operator * ( const Element &obj)
{
    d *= obj.d;
    return *this;
}
```

This doesn't work. It throws an error saying: "no match for 'operator*' in '8 * c'

In the main file I have:

```
d = a = 8 * c - 4 + b;
```

where d, a, c and b are all objects of class Element

Comment: I'll recommend the [Operator Overloading FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/46642).

Comment: 8 is not an `Element`. It is treated as an int. The code You show only allows multiplication of two `Element`.

Comment: how then do I get it to work with multiplication of an Element and an int?

Comment: How about reading the below answers? there is more than one example there....

Comment: [shameless self publicity] I wrote an [entry](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/operator-overloading.html) about operator overloading that you might want to take a look at, in particular you should read about the differences between overloading a binary operator as a free function or a member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really have to understand what you are doing here, you are overloading the '*' operator for the Element class, but you're doing so while expecting another element has a 'parameter'.

The code you wrote is actually expecting this kind of code

```
Element v, w, a;
a = v * w;
```

As mentionned, you might want to take a look at : http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/

Comment: hmm ok i have read a bit on the learCPP website.. am going to try and implement some of the code written there.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

that's because you overloaded operator * only for `Element * Element`, while for `c * 8` you would have to implement `Element Element::operator * ( const int i)`

Comment: The expression is 8 * c, a member operator will not do. Op needs to make use of a global operator overload and const Element & references with a parametrized Element constructor.

Comment: you will notice that I wrote `c * 8` in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the 8 * c expression  (int, Element) with a non-member overload like

```
Element operator* (const Element& leftHandSide, const Element& rightHandSide){
   return Element( leftHandSide.d * rightHandSide.d);
}
```

By using `const Element&` you can make use of a constructor with a signature like `Element::Element(int )` for type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing operator implementation allows you to multiply two `Element` objects together.
But, according to the client code in your 'main file', you need to be able to multiply an Element object by a scalar value; 8 in this case.

So what you need is an additional operator which takes a double as its parameter:
Something like the following:

```
Element Element::operator * ( const double scalar ) const
{
    const Element e( d * scalar );
    return e;
}
```

Here I am assuming that your Element class has a constructor which takes a single scalar parameter, and assigns it to d.

Note also that your existing implementation of operator* is semantically strange,
as it mutates the internal state of d (with *= ).
This is almost certainly not what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you and a warning for your operator overload.

Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Element {
    double d;
    Element(double d) {this->d = d;}
    Element operator*(const Element &obj) {
        d *= obj.d;
        return *this;
    }
};

Element operator*(const int i, const Element& e) {
    return Element(static_cast<double>(i) * e.d);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Element& e) {
    os << e.d;
    return os;
}

int main() {
        Element e(2);
        cout << "Product of 8 and e: " << 8*e << '\n';

        // This shows why your overload is a bad idea:
        Element a(3);
        cout << "a is " << a << '\n'; // prints 3
        cout << "Now its product with e is: " << a*e << '\n'; // prints 6
        cout << "Surprise: a is now " << a << '\n'; // prints 6
}
```

Your original overload did not work, cause it wasn't even called. Your expression was similar to

```
a = 8*c
```

where 8 is of type int and when C++ parses this expression from left to right it sees that 8 is of type int and tries to search for an overload of operator*(const Element&) in the type int and it cannot find it, cause it does not know and is not supposed to know anything about your own user-defined type. So if you want your own class to interact with the other types you either need to embed an overload of operator* as a member function into that other type or declare it as the external function like I did in my solution.

Now the warning. Your original operator overload is ill-defined, cause it modifies the original object, which is considered to be an unexpected behavior. I show this in the code above. It's like multiplying 8 by 2 would give you 16, but at the same time make 16 out of your 8. What you really want to do is to create a new element in your multiplication operator and return it:

```
struct Element {
    double d;
    Element(double d) {this->d = d;}
    Element operator*( const Element &obj) {
        return Element(this->d * obj.d);
    }
};
```

Damn these answers take heck a lot of time... I should be working though :\